# How to uninstall a device administrator app that wont deactivate?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, lg-optimus-one, device-administrator

My cousin decided to download an app on my phone as a joke. I tried to uninstall it but it just won't uninstall. It's an administrator app, I tried to deactivate it but it won't deactivate. Whenever I try to deactivate it, it shuts down my phone. What should I do?  I tried to root my phone and delete it that didn't work either.

How can I uninstall this app?

Comment: No cousin is worth this kind of effort. Place in his left hand; retrieve cash from his right. Its his problem then.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually uninstall the app with steps below:

**ROOT IS REQUIRED**

**I am not responsible if you damage your phone, just follow steps below and nothing will happen.**

1. Download a root file explorer like [Root Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree) from the play store.
2. Open the app.
3. Go to `/data/app/`.
4. Delete the apk of the app.
5. Check if also a directory of the app exists in `/data/data/`. If so, delete that directory. (The directory is the package name.)
6. Reboot your phone.
7. The app now should now be uninstalled.